# How to position layout divs vertically without using parent div

Tags: css, html

I’m trying to drift away from using tables and I'm now trying to create a simple div-based layout - header, content, footer divs with 100% width and no parent div. But I'm having a little problem with it. My content and footer divs overlap header div if I ever insert anything there. They appear right in the middle of the header div. If they are empty they appear normally. But the moment I insert header image in it the problem starts.

I tried to change float and display properties, but it gives me strange output. Can anyone help me position them vertically one after another?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="topDiv"> topmenu</div>
<div id="headerDiv">
<div class="innerDiv"><img src=" photos/header.jpg" /></div>
</div><br /><br />
<div id="contentsDiv"> content</div>
<div id="footDiv"> footer </div>
```

And here are the css styles:

```
div#topDiv{
width:100%;
height:20px;
background-color:#800000;
text-align:center;
margin: 0px;
position:absolute;
}

 div#headerDiv{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
background-color:#0FF;
text-align:center;
margin: 0px;
 }

  div#contentsDiv{
width:100%;
margin: 0px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#0CC;
position:absolute;
  }

  div#footDiv{
width:100%;
margin: 0px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#CF3;
position:absolute;
}

 .innerDiv{
width:930px;
height:100px;
margin:auto;
background-color:#C30;
position:relevant;
 }
```

Comment: Do you want this to be a fluid or fixed layout? Setting some `positions` might help. There are dozens of CSS-only layout helper sites... I'm sure you can find one that fits your needs.

Comment: I want it to bi fixed. so all layout divs follow one another in a vertical order topmenu, header, content, footer

Comment: what tipe of position shall i assign to layout divs and what for inner?

Comment: I tried assigning 'absolute position` to the layout divs and `relative` to the inner ones. but still result is quite peculiar

Comment: Try this article... http://www.techrepublic.com/article/creating-a-fixed-width-layout-with-css/

Comment: thanks I will have a look. just a moment

Comment: I tried follow the suggestion from the example and changed `position` in the divs part. I will update css code in my post. but still content post is totally our of screen and footer post overlapping the header image

Comment: is it something to do with my size? I want it to be screen wide. nthats why i put 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all `position:absolute` from `CSS` rules and you are done.

Comment: No issues. I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute and relative positioning a lot
and they are making your layout look Bad and elements are over lapping.

Also you don't need to define margin and every other properties many times

```
html, body{
width 100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

[Horizontal Layout](http://jsfiddle.net/4rN5r/1/)

[CSS-Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[Vertical Layout](http://jsfiddle.net/4rN5r/2/)

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: @meks start by using a css-reset, have a quick go through of the css properties. Mostly Practice. i have given a css-reset link in the answer

Comment: @meks check the vertical layout too

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you. You don't need to specify `width=100` Without defining a width, it is 100% by default. Simply specify the width you want for the `body` and every other container will be that width. `float: left;` will prevent containers from stacking vertically. They will actually stack horizontally.

Rather than using many `Ids` for `Div`, you can simplify the tags with `HTML5` tags in such a way as below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            menu {
                height: 20px;
                background-color: #800000;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            header {
                background-color: #0FF;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0px;
            }

            article {
                margin: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #0CC;
            }

            footer {
                margin: 0px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #CF3;
            }

            section {
                height: 100px;
                margin: auto;
                background-color: #C30;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <menu>topmenu</menu>
        <header>Header
        <article>
            <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/1-google-logo-tutorial.gif" />
        </article>
        </header>
        <section>content</section>
        <footer>footer </footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank for your suggestion but I need those divs to be bigger than 930px and occupy 100% of the screen. that's the problem

Comment: yes I removed 100% width property and they are taking the size of their content

Comment: this is exactly opposite of what I want

Comment: I'm kinda puzzled. why don't they just pile vertically?

Comment: @meks Im not sure what you mean. My code stacks containers vertically and takes up the whole width. Isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: I pasted your code and its doesnt work the way you said. the width only 930 px. but i want it to occupy the whole width of the screen

Comment: @meks As I explained below in my answer, if you want 100%, simply remove `width: 930px;` from the code.

Comment: besides how about those users whose browsers do not support html5

Comment: it works with me perfectly with me even withthe simple divs. if the code is like this: `<div id="topDiv"> topmenu</div>
<div id="headerDiv">header</div><br />
<div id="contentsDiv"> content</div>
<div id="footDiv"> footer </div>`

Comment: when the divs are emty they are piled up vertically. but when i insert the div with a picture in the header the mess occures

Comment: @meks Yes, divs with Ids will work. The new tags are simpler way of writing divs with Ids and easier to see. The code I provided does not have issues with images added. You probably set a property incorrectly in your CSS. Check the updated code.

Comment: the size of headerdiv increases and the footer and contednt divs stay at the same palce and above the header

Comment: @meks Update your question code to clarify what you mean. And please accept the answer if it answers your original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. `position: absolute ` wasthe problem

Comment: @meks My code did not have `position: absolute` properties. It solved the problems you were having and also simplified the need to use `Div Id`. It is a better answer.